# Choosing the right Time control for suggestions(onClick) [SAPUI5]

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am looking for a time control which can provide suggestions of certain times **but**

1. It should provide suggestions onclick, i.e. you click the field and suggestions are showcased as a list, not that you have to type in something.

What i have found: Input with type="Time"

```
<Input type="Time" suggest="onSuggestTime"/>
```

**Issue**: it delievers suggestions when you type something in, i need for it to be onclick, as you click the `input` field your recieve your suggestions

Comment: [`InputType.Time` is deprecated](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.InputType#properties) since UI5 1.9.1. For time inputs, the [`sap.m.TimePicker`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.TimePicker) control should be used typically.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer my question. `TimePicker` doesn't support suggestions/onClick event as described above, only change

Comment: By "suggestions" do you mean the value help (F4)? Or what are you suggesting in `onSuggestTime`?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann, by suggestion i mean https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Input/sample/sap.m.sample.InputSuggestionsDynamic, just it delievers an list of suggestions, but not based on an entry as is the case with the example above, but just simply by clicking the `inputfield`